# Cloudera Manager API to fetch the list of Flume agents

Tags: api

I am trying to fetch the number of Flume agents are running on My CDH5.8 cluster using Cloudera Manager API .

https://cloudera.github.io/cm_api/

Till now i could not figure out which RESTful Model I should consider or the related Java class. If any one can help or to inform the the referenced Java class to look into that will be great

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the following API:

[https://cloudera.github.io/cm_api/apidocs/v13/path__clusters_-clusterName-*services*-serviceName-_roles.html](https://cloudera.github.io/cm_api/apidocs/v13/path__clusters_-clusterName-_services_-serviceName-_roles.html)

The size of the `items` array in the JSON object returned will be the number of Flume agents.  To find the number of running agents, for each item, check that `roleState` equals `STARTED`.

The Java class `ApiRole` is probably what you need.  This code snippet from the whirr-cm example is close to what you want.

https://github.com/cloudera/whirr-cm/blob/edb38ca7faa3e4bb2c23450ff0183c2dd631dcf4/src/main/java/com/cloudera/whirr/cm/server/impl/CmServerImpl.java#L486

```
        for (ApiService apiService : apiResourceRootV3.getClustersResource().getServicesResource(getName(cluster))
            .readServices(DataView.SUMMARY)) {
          for (ApiRole apiRole : apiResourceRootV3.getClustersResource().getServicesResource(getName(cluster))
              .getRolesResource(apiService.getName()).readRoles()) {
            if (apiRole.getRoleState().equals(ApiRoleState.STARTED)) {
              servicesNotStarted.remove(apiRole.getName());
            }
          }
        }
```

You would just need to limit this to the Flume service.

https://cloudera.github.io/cm_api/javadoc/5.11.0/index.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I shall go through the code. I found a workaround using RESTful model                                                                [ curl -u admin:admin "localhost:7180/api/v13/clusters/Cloudera%20QuickSart/servic‌​es/{servicename}/roles" ]                                Now I am trying to stop the role(flume agent) but failed. I tried with                         [ curl -X POST -u admin:admin "localhost:7180/api/v13/clusters/Cloudera%20QuickS tart/services/flume/roles/agent11/roleCommands/stop"   ]

Comment: If you're trying to stop a Flume agent, you'll need to do something like this: curl -X POST -u admin:admin -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{ "items": ["agent11"] }' 'localhost:7180/api/v13/clusters/Cloudera%20QuickS tart/services/flume/roleCommands/stop'.   See https://github.com/cloudera/cm_api/wiki/Start-Stop-Restart-JobTracker-Role and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004746/restart-jobtracker-through-cloudera-manager-api for more examples.